# Send data to a php webpage using electric imp

Tags: php

I am using a php website with electric imp. I am trying to send data from my electric imp to my website and retrieve the data on my website which I will later use as a variable.

Device code (electric imp)

```
function setLed(state) {
if(state == 1)
{
```

(led5 is pin5)

```
led5.write(state) ; 
server.log("Light : " + state);
local code = 1 * 2 + state ; // 1 is pin number 
server.log ("switch " + code ) ;
agent.send ( "swdata", code ) ;

}
```

Agent Code (electric imp)

```
//  define the http handler
function requestHandler(request, response) {

local state = request.query["led"].tointeger() ;
device.send("led", state); 
response.send(200, "OK"); 

log(state);
 } 

// register the http handler
http.onrequest(requestHandler);


function log (code) {
 const url = "http://jnghgi.php";
local headers = { "Content-Type" : "application/json"} ;

local state = code % 2 ;
local pin = (code - state) / 2 ;

server.log ("state"+state+" pin"+pin) ;
local body = { "pin" : pin , "state" : state } ;
  local jsonBody = http.jsonencode(body) ;

//  POST the values
local request = http.post(url, headers, jsonBody);
local response = request.sendsync();

server.log(response.statuscode + ": " + response.body);
   }


 device.on("swdata", log) ;
```

php code to (website)

```
<?php

$jsonbody = file_get_contents('php://input') ;
```

dumping the $json body gives me an output of string(0) "" and dumping jsonobj gives a null. as far as I can tell the problem is occurring with the transfer of the data from the electric imp to the website

```
var_dump($jsonbody);

$jsonobj = json_decode($jsonbody) ;
var_dump($jsonobj);
$state = $jsonobj -> state ;
$pin = $jsonobj -> pin ;
$result = updatered($state, $pin) ;  
//var_dump($result);

//var_dump($state);

function updatered(){
    include ("db.php") ;    
    //  connect to the database to get current state
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if (!$conn) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    echo "fail";        }
    $sql = "UPDATE LED 
    SET LOn = $state
    WHERE ID = $pin";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


}


?>
```

on my website I have attempted to retrieve the data using a $_GET but that was unsuccessful, if anyone has any knowledge on how I could retrieve the data then help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: just wanted to add that electric imp uses squirrel

Comment: I have no idea about how _electric imp_ works, but we don't see code (PHP), so, have you tried checking the value of `$_REQUEST`? Or even using file_get_contents of `php://input`?

Comment: @FirstOne yeah sorry about that last one, misunderstood something. fixed it to uses php:input but still getting a problem, I have checked the http on the imp and its correct, any idea why the data isn't being transfered

Comment: Try debugging separate parts of the project. Check if each is working on it's own (make a the request to a dummy request handler to validate it - make requests to that php script with a program such as postman). Test some debugging you can think of..

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was because I didn't pass $state and $pin through my parameters for my function:

```
function updatered($state, $pin)
```